# AJAX call not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to use an AJAX call to render a partial view when a radio button is selected. I have searched and have tried what appears to be the best approach via comments on Stack. When I click the radio button, I have no result, in debug, I get a Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error? Any assistance would be great.

Partial View Names:

```
_BOA.cshtml
_TA.cshtml
_MNB.cshtml
```

View:

```
                <td class="radio-inline">
                    @Html.RadioButton("bankSelect", "MNBConvert", false, new { @class = "radioMNB" }) MNB Conversion
                    @Html.RadioButton("bankSelect", "BOAConvert", false, new { @class = "radioBOA" }) BOA Conversion
                    @Html.RadioButton("bankSelect", "TAConvert", false, new { @class = "radioTA" }) TA Conversion
                </td>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[name=bankSelect]").on('change', function () {
               // var $radio = $(this);
                var checked = $("input[name='bankSelect']:checked").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetBankToConvert", "Home")',
                    data: checked,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#renderPartialView").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetBankToConvert(string bankSelect)
        {
            if (bankSelect == "MNBConvert")
            {
                return PartialView("_MNB");
            }
            else if (bankSelect == "BOAConvert")
            {
                return PartialView("_BOA");
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_TA");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't affect anything but instead of ActionResult you can change it to `PartialViewResult`. And have you tried to set a breakpoint or something on the console?

Comment: @BrianWhite - Not to sound ignorant, but how do I pull a server log?

Comment: @JorgeF - I did set a breakpoint, it does not go into the function.

Comment: That depends on your server.  Do you run it?  If so, what software?  Is it hosted (e.g. AppEngine)?

Comment: Currently running locally. But we do run the webfarm.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't sending a key/value pair as data, only a `value`.

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetBankToConvert", "Home")',
    data: {bankSelect: checked },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#renderPartialView").html(data);
    }
});
```

WHen in doubt, inspect the actual request in network tab of browser dev tools to see exactly what is sent and received among all the other components of a request